# Explanation about AND or OR operations in my C sharp code

Tags: c#, logical-operators

I am trying to analyze some code in C#. I have some misunderstanding problem with converting numbers and may be with AND operations in C# code. I have the code as shown below.

```
        public void SerialNumber(UInt32 number)
    {
        _sensorNumber=0;
        if (number == 0)
            number = (UInt32)(USB.Id << 16) | (_sensorNumber << 10) | 1;

        SerialNumber = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}",
            (number & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16,
            (number & 0x0000FC00) >> 10,
            number & 0x000003FF);
    }
```

Can anyone explain me clearly what does this code do? I need explanation in "SerialNumber" line.
When i tried to debug this piece of code I am observing two different situations.

1) when i have the number = 65668097;
then i am getting "SerialNumber = 1002-0-1

2) when i have the number = 0;
the it is getting USB.Id = 15152; and after that i didn't understand what operations is taking place then finally number= 993001473
 then i am getting "SerialNumber = 15152-0-1

Please can anyone explain me what happening with AND, OR operations.

Answer (score 2):

`&` and `|` are logical *and* and *or* respectively. That means that if you do it with two numbers, their bit representation is logically compared and you get the result. E.g.:

101011 and 110010 = 100010

101011 or 110010 = 111011

`>>` is a bit shifting operator and the number that follows tells how many shifts you should perform. You can read about it here: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpShiftOperators.aspx

I hope it will help you get started.

**EDIT**:
In case you do not know. 0xFFFF0000 is a hexadecimal representation of a number. More about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see the numbers in hexadecimal format to better understand that code.
The serial number (as number or as string) is a combination (encoding in a single integer) of 3 different things: the USB ID, the sensor number and ... something else. The USB Id occupies the first 16 bits, the sensor number the next 6 and there's a last part on 10 bits (16+10+6 = 32 bits = sizeof(UInt32)): 0xFFFF0000 is the mask for the first 16 bits (0xFFFF = 2^16-1), 0xFC00 for the next 6, 0x3FF for the last 10 bits (0x3FF = 1023 = 2^10 - 1, 0xFFFF = 0xFC00 + 0x3FF). 
In brief, the "bitwise AND" (&) is there for separating the three parts from the full integer and the "bitwise OR" (|) is there to compose back the number from its parts.

Comment: The function expects proper input values but 0 is not proper input, so a default serial `number` is built from the current USB ID (`USB.Id`). That's the explanation for the line where bitwise OR is used.